# SQL Query slow beginning of each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

I have a basic query below.

```
Select [ID] 
FROM MyTable 
Where [TextBlobField] like '%test%'
```

This query takes a long time when I first run it each day. After that it only takes about 5 seconds. Next morning back to long query time. Is this because SQL is caching a index temporary?

How can I make this fast all the time? NOTE: I do not have permission to create my own index on the table. I can create a Stored Procedure, but don't know if that help? Should I create a view?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Query is coming from a C# application.

Comment: It is running in SQL 2005.

Comment: Yes SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3):

it is highly unlikely that the reason is an index cache.  The reason:  your query cannot make use of an index for the `where` clause.  Although `like` can use an index, it cannot when the pattern starts with a wildcard.

However, you are on the right track.  The reason is probably because the table itself needs to be read and cached in memory.

Although `like` doesn't use an index, you might be able to modify the query to use `contains`, taking advantage of full text indexing.  You can learn more about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).

Comment: I found some existing views on the table? Would that have increased performance or is it going to be the same where the first query on the view takes a long time?

Comment: @user1887198 . . . Something would appear to be happening at night that is resulting in a cold cache (at least with respect to this table).  You could schedule a job using SQL Server Agent to run a query on the table before anyone else does.

Answer (score 2):

That's usually because of caching.

One solution is to call that query once every morning automatically before your system is used by end users - that triggers the caching.